# VBA Find and Replace User-form Capitalizes Randomly and Copies New Text Multiple Times

Tags: vba, ms-word, userform

I have been trying to create a userform that my coworkers can use to update specific parts of a Word document (ie computer parts) without having to search for the parts in the document.  Sort of streamlining find and replace.

Using VBA bookmarks and the `.Find` function I have largely accomplished this task. However, in testing there have been multiple instances where the new part name has either copied over twice (ie I type "Part_Number_1234" and get "Part_Number_12341234") or the new text is capitalized.

I do realize that part of the issue is related to the fact that I am changing text twice when I change the bookmark text and use the find and replace function. I attempted to mitigate this by using the `wdFindAsk` wrap parameter and moving the text to be changed near the top of the document; however, this only seemed to occasionally solve the problem as it still happens frequently.

I have tried using different wrap parameters and moving the actual text around in the Word document (as Word loops through the entire document in find and replace)

```
'Changes bookmarks to keep list of all parts

Dim BMRange As Range
Set BMRange = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(BookmarkToUpdate).Range
BMRange.Text = TextToUse
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add TextToUse, BMRange

'Finds and replaces the specified part with the new part

With Selection.Find
.ClearFormatting
.Text = ComboBox1.Value
.Replacement.ClearFormatting
.Replacement.Text = TextBox1.Value
.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, _
Wrap:=wdFindAsk
End With
```

**Example of what I'm trying to do with this code:**

I want to change part number: "Part_12345"

I select the bookmark with that part number in the user-form and type in the 
new part number: "Part_Number_12345678"

Result is supposed to change the bookmark and the text in the document to 
the new value specified.

However, about 50% of the time the result for the body text will be either:

> "Part_Number_PART_NUMBER_12345678"
>   *or* 
>   "PART_NUMBER_12345678"

And within that 50% the bookmark text will be:

> "Part_Number_12345678678"

(Using wdFindAsk has helped this issue)

The code above are the two instances in my code where text is changed. The first section is so I can use bookmarks to keep a list of new parts. The bottom is to replace the part name in the rest of the document.

Comment: Could you please use the [edit] link to add a bit of sample text this would run on, as well as expected and actual results? That will help us determine where the problem is - without the information anything we do will be a bit hit-and-miss... What I'm looking for is a [mcve] in "tech speak" :-)

Comment: Have you considered using `REF` fields for the "part names in the document" that are changed using Find/Replace. (Cross-references to the bookmarks.) After updating the fields in the document they would automatically reflect the content of the bookmark - no need to find/replace. Another possibility would be mapped content controls, rather than the bookmark and REF field combination.

Comment: So REF fields are a way of connecting bookmarks to other portions of the text?  So when the bookmark is changed the text in the REF field in question is changed as well? @CindyMeister

Comment: Yes, that's correct. It's what Word uses internally when you insert a cross-reference to a bookmark.

Comment: Perfect, I will try to implement it Monday when I'm back at work.  I'll update this post with how it goes.  Thank you! @CindyMeister

Comment: @CindyMeister I don't think REF fields will work in this instance. In order to change the title of the bookmark and the text, I need to save the range of the old bookmark and create a new bookmark using that old range, hence the old text that the REF field is looking at is gone. So I end up with a "Error! Reference source not found.bookmark_name" I am going to look into mapped content controls now.

Comment: I don't understand the problem? If you recreate the bookmark around a different range - using the same bookmark *name* - the REF field should continue to show the content after the bookmark has been recreated?

Comment: That's the key, with the method I was using I needed to change the bookmark name itself.  However, I realized that I didn't even need my user-form code at all (which is why I was changing the bookmark name, I was populating a list of bookmark names in the user-form).  All I needed to do was create the bookmarks and link them to the specified word I wanted to update with an REF field and then create a button to update the fields.  This approach is way simpler and produces consistent results. Problem solved. Thank you @CindyMeister for all the help!

Comment: You're quite welcome :-)

Answer (score 1):

I realized that I didn't even need my user-form code at all (which is why I was changing the bookmark name, I was populating a list of bookmark names in the user-form). All I needed to do was create the bookmarks and link them to the specified word I wanted to update with an REF field and then create a button to update the fields (using this: "ActiveDocument.Fields.Update"). This approach is way simpler and produces consistent results. Problem solved.